# Excel formula to say if time is within a certain hourly range

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column(A) of times, stored in time format. And I have columns(B-M) of hourly times, 08:00:00 - 09:00:00 etc. I want Excel to put a 1 in the correct hourly column based on the time, and hopefully a zero in all the others. I thought `COUNTIFS` could do this, I tried
`=COUNTIFS(A2, ">=08:00:00", A2, "<09:00:00")` So if the time is between 8 and 9am I would get a 1 in column B. Obviously it didn't work, hence why I'm here.
[Excel book 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp1F5.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
=AND($A2>=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(B$1,5)),$A2<TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B$1,5)))
```

Put it in `B2` and pull it downwards and sideways. This takes the time ranges from the first row and looks if the time from the first column is inside the current range.

If you don't want `True` or `False`(in the example pictures it's in german) you can multiply the formula by 1 to get `0` and `1` as results or wrap an `if` around to get any desired output.

[image]